# Color folders in ZSH based off directory depth

Tags: zsh, colors, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I'm currently editing the *agnoster* theme from *oh-my-zsh* to my preferences, and was wondering if there is some way to color the names of directories in the status bar based off depth. Something like...

```
~(red)/.config(orange)/oh-my-zsh(yellow)
```

I was initially using the *powerline* package from the ubuntu repo, but found it to be slow so I switched to *zsh* themes. While using *powerline* I was kind of able to do what I wanted, but could only change the color of the current working directory. My configuration was something like...

```
"cwd": {"fg": 'color', "bg": 'color', "attrs": []}

"cwd:current_folder": {"fg": 'color', "bg": 'color', "attrs": []}
```

Any help in creating this rainbow monstrosity would be greatly appreciated. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using Terminator if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which does it. It's not perfect, absolutely no portable but it seems to works. To use it in `$PS1` you just have to change `$fg_` and `$bg_` (with `%F`/`%B` or `$fg`/`$bg`, I don't remember) and setup and precmd hook (`add-zsh-hook precmd function_precmd`) with a function you will create and that will modify a variable used in `$PS1`.

To customize the function, you just need to set PRE_ASSOC correctly.

```
function colorize_array () {
    local reset='\033[0m'

    for (( i = 1; i <= $# ; i++ )); do
        pre=""

        if (( $+PRE_ASSOC[$i] )); then
            pre=$PRE_ASSOC[$i]
        elif (( $+PRE_ASSOC[$(( $i - $# - 1 ))] )) ;then
            pre=$PRE_ASSOC[$(( $i - $# - 1 ))]
        else
            pre=$PRE_ASSOC[default]
        fi
        echo -n -e $pre$@[$i]$reset
    done
}

typeset -A fg_ bg_ 
typeset -A PRE_ASSOC

fg_=([black]="\033[30m" [white]="\033[37m" [red]="\033[31m" [yellow]="\033[33m" [cyan]="\033[36m")
bg_=([black]="\033[40m" [white]="\033[47m" [red]="\033[41m" [yellow]="\033[43m" [cyan]="\033[46m")

PRE_ASSOC=([default]="$fg_[cyan]/" [1]="$fg_[red]"  [-1]="$fg_[yellow]/")

local pwd="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
pwd_list=(${(s:/:)pwd})

out=$(colorize_array $pwd_list)
echo $out
```

The code is far from being perfect, but it works.